# How to use simplexlsxgen in php to Generate sheet and download in ajax javascript while sharing JS array from jacascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php

### I have been trying to generate an excel sheet and download using simplexlsxgen (PHP)

### Here is my Github documentation too

[Link](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen)

### What I Need

1. I have a JSON Array in my javascript I have to pass it to the PHP file through javascript AJAX where I generate my excel sheet and download it to my Local disk

### The Sample Code I have Tried

### In my index.php file

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="export.php">Export to Excel Sheet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### In My export.php file

```
<?php
include ("SimpleXLSXGen.php");

$books = [
  
    ['Monday', 'App', 'Lynley Dodd', 'Mallinson Rendel', 'NZ'],
    ['',       'Pos', 'Lynley Dodd', 'Mallinson Rendel', 'NZ']
    
];
$xlsx = Shuchkin\SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $books );
$xlsx->mergeCells('A3:A5');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A6:A8');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A9:A11');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A12:A14');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A15:A17');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A18:A20');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A21:A23');
$xlsx->mergeCells('A24:A26');
$xlsx->mergeCells('C1:L1');
$xlsx->saveAs('books.xlsx');
 $xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');

?>
```

### Conclusion

1. If I Use the above code the array is converted to an excel sheet and downloaded successfully.

### The Problem

!. I have the array in my javascript file So I have to pass that array From my Javascript to my PHP File using ajax javascript.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'export.php',
  data: {
  books:books
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
                   
      }
      });
```

2. But If I just pass the data like this the excel sheet is not downloading.

### The alternative Code I have tried

### In my index.php file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JS array to Excel</title>
</head>
<script>

    function array2excel() {
        var books = [
            ["ISBN", "title", "author", "publisher", "ctry"],
            [618260307, "The Hobbit", "J. R. R. Tolkien", "Houghton Mifflin", "USA"],
            [908606664, "Slinky Malinki", "Lynley Dodd", "Mallinson Rendel", "NZ"]
        ];
        var json = JSON.stringify(books);
    
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
        request.onload = function () {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var file = new Blob([this.response], {type: this.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')});
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var filename = "", m;
                var disposition = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disposition && (m = /"([^"]+)"/.exec(disposition)) !== null) {
                    filename = m[1];
                }
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = fileURL;
                } else {
                    a.href = fileURL;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                alert("Error: " + this.status + "  " + this.statusText);
            }
        }
        
        request.open('POST', "array2excel.php");
        request.responseType = "blob";
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send("array2excel=" + encodeURIComponent(json));
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="array2excel()" value="array2excel" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

### In my array2excel.php file

```
<?php // array2excel.php
if (isset($_POST['array2excel'])) {
    require __DIR__.'/simplexlsxgen/src/SimpleXLSXGen.php';
    $data = json_decode($_POST['array2excel'], false);
    \Shuchkin\SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray($data)->downloadAs('file.xlsx');
    return;
}
?>
```

### Problem with the Alternative code

1. The file is downloading but the file is been corrupted and downloaded as an HTML file instead of an excel Sheet File.

### What Do I Need

1. I need to pass My JSON array which is in my javascript to the export/array2excel.php file using javascript ajax using the post method
2. welcome to suggest any alternative.

Comment: https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen/issues/32#issuecomment-840770543  seems that you have to do `exit()` after `downloadAs()`. Thats what the repo owner says.

Comment: I have tried still the result is same

Comment: Then try the debugging that was noted there. I havent used this repo yet, so cant help. I wanted to give a possible direction for problem-lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an html file (when calling simpleXLSXGen, then you have a syntax error or a runtime error (file not found, permission denied ..., required file not found et al). Try to test separately the generator and the rest of the program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).